# Capturar o evento change em um p:selectOneMenu do tipo Enum

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Não consigo capturar o evento de mudança do componente p:selectOneMenu, cuja a fonte de carregamento é um enum. Registrei na minha view o evento change do Ajax, contudo o método do listener não é chamado.

A minha view utiliza o seguinte código para fazer o carregamento do combo:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="analise" value="#{fooMB.analise}" converter="AnaliseConverter">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione"/>
    <f:selectItems value="#{fooMB.carregarComboAnalise}" var="analise" itemLabel="#{analise.descricao}" itemValue="#{analise}/>
    <f:ajax event="change" listener="#{fooMB.changeComboAnalise}"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

O enum tem o seguinte código:

```
public enum AnaliseEnum {

    AVALIACAO("Avaliação"), 
    SUGESTAO("Sugestão"), 
    RECLAMACAO("Reclamação"), 
    OUTROS("Outros");

    private String descricao;

    private AnaliseEnum(String descricao) {
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }

    public String getDescricao() {
        return this.descricao;
    }
}
```

O meu ManagedBean possui o seguinte método usado para realizar o carregamento do combo:

```
public AnaliseEnum[] carregarComboAnalise() {
    return  AnaliseEnum.values();
}
```

O meu converter tem o seguinte código:

```
@FacesConverter(value = "AnaliseConverter")
public class AnaliseConverter extends EnumConverter {

    public AnaliseConverter() {
        super(AnaliseEnum.class);
    }
}
```

O método adicionado no listener do componente não imprime a informação no console, ou seja, não é acionado.

```
public void changeComboAnalise(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
    System.out.println("Deveria fazer alguma coisa aqui, mas não faz .... ");
}
```

O combo carrega normalmente, mas o método changeComboAnalise() chamado no evento "change" não é executado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bem, a captura do evento change em um componente `p:selectOneMenu` não difere em nada da forma como foi implementada pelo autor da pergunta: **é simples assim**. Então, se não há nenhum problema no modo como se está interceptando o evento, deduz-se que a falhar esteja em um outro ponto, ou  em outra parte do código que envolve esta operação.

#### O motivo da falha

Depois de alguns dias com muita raiva por não conseguir identificar o problema e me achando um burro por isso, descobri que a falha estava relacionada a um setter  mal implementado. Isso mesmo que você leu, um setter mal implementado. Meu método setter não estava passando o parâmetro como o faz no exemplo abaixo:

```
public void setAnalise(AnaliseEnum analise) {
    this.analise = analise;
}
```

#### Conversor genérico para Enum: GenericEnumConverter

O [OmniFaces](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/) é um projeto desenvolvido por Bauke Scholtz, o [BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc), e [Arjan Tijms](https://stackoverflow.com/users/472792/arjan-tijms). É uma biblioteca utilitária que fornece um conjunto de classes, componentes, a fim de facilitar o desenvolvimento com JSF.

Como forma de dirimir a redundância de código adotei o OmniFaces. Uma das classes fornecidas pelo projeto é a classe [GenericEnumConverter](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/converters/GenericEnumConverter) que fornece um conversor genérico para um Enum, removendo assim a necessidade de se criar um conversor para cada Enum de meu projeto.